# get UserId into second table

Tags: c#, sql-server, userid

I´m trying to create a MSSQL tabel where after a UserRegistation (create user wizard) the UserID from "aspnet_Users (dbo)" will be copied into this new tabel.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `will be copied into this new tabel`, what??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an automated system that responds on specific actions, a `TRIGGER` is what you're most likely looking for.

In your case, it sounds as if you want to respond to `INSERT`s happening on the dbo.aspnet_Users table. The code would be something similar to this  (pseudo-code, not tested):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgNewUser ON dbo.aspnet_Users 
AFTER INSERT 
AS
INSERT INTO myTable (userID)
SELECT userID FROM INSERTED
```

`INSERTED` is a special logical table that essentially has the same structure as the table the trigger is created on, and it will contain the latest row `INSERT`ed into the table. Thus, you can use that to capture newly added records, and have the trigger take appropriate actions.

More info on Triggers:

[Use the inserted and deleted Tables on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

[CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)